# ML Kit Barcode Scanner (used in reactnative-camera) cut displayValue after U+0000 / NULL

Tags: objective-c, xcode, google-mlkit

I am trying to scan ECC Data Matrix code with binary content, but if there is a NULL byte I can only get the string up to there.

Unfortunately, I have no control over these matrix codes, as I have to scan the codes provided.
Does somebody has any idea?

Is it possibly to convert the rawData?

It would be enough if I received the content as a hex value.

The rawData is allready hex, but not as expected, maybe it is also corrupt or in an unknown coding.

Does somebody know encoding of rawdata?

see https://developers.google.com/ml-kit/reference/ios/mlkitbarcodescanning/api/reference/Classes/MLKBarcode#rawdata

Comment: I was going to recommend using Apple's framework instead of Google's, but I see that Apple also returns barcode-encoded data as a string, instead of data object. Therefore, I imagine the NULL byte will be a problem there as well. https://developer.apple.com/documentation/vision/vndetectbarcodesrequest?language=objc

Comment: Thanks for comment, but i found a solution for me today in Javascript, because in Objective C NUL Byte is always a Problem for strings.

Answer (score 0):

I found a solution for me:

Here my Code for React-Native:

```
import {DataMatrixDecodedBitStreamParser, ZXingStringEncoding} from "@zxing/library";
const bin2hex = (s)=> {
  //  discuss at: https://locutus.io/php/bin2hex/
  // original by: Kevin van Zonneveld (https://kvz.io)
  // bugfixed by: Onno Marsman (https://twitter.com/onnomarsman)
  // bugfixed by: Linuxworld
  // improved by: ntoniazzi (https://locutus.io/php/bin2hex:361#comment_177616)
  //   example 1: bin2hex('Kev')
  //   returns 1: '4b6576'
  //   example 2: bin2hex(String.fromCharCode(0x00))
  //   returns 2: '00'
  let i;
  let l;
  let o = '';
  let n;
  s += '';
  for (i = 0, l = s.length; i < l; i++) {
    n = s.charCodeAt(i)
        .toString(16);
    o += n.length < 2 ? '0' + n : n;
  }
  return o;
}
const hex2bin = (s)=> {
  //  discuss at: https://locutus.io/php/hex2bin/
  // original by: Dumitru Uzun (https://duzun.me)
  //   example 1: hex2bin('44696d61')
  //   returns 1: 'Dima'
  //   example 2: hex2bin('00')
  //   returns 2: '\x00'
  //   example 3: hex2bin('2f1q')
  //   returns 3: false
  const ret = []
  let i = 0
  let l
  s += ''
  for (l = s.length; i < l; i += 2) {
    const c = parseInt(s.substr(i, 1), 16);
    const k = parseInt(s.substr(i + 1, 1), 16);
    if (isNaN(c) || isNaN(k)) return false;
    ret.push((c << 4) | k);
  }
  return String.fromCharCode.apply(String, ret);
}
const fromHexString = hexString => new Uint8Array(hexString.match(/.{1,2}/g).map(byte => parseInt(byte, 16)));
const matrixcodeRAW2HEX = raw_hex => {
  let data = fromHexString(raw_hex);
  try {
    global.Buffer = global.Buffer || require('buffer').Buffer;
    ZXingStringEncoding.customDecoder = (stringContent, encodingName) => {
      let encodingName2 = encodingName;
      if(encodingName.toLowerCase()=="iso-8859-1"){
        encodingName2="latin1";
      }
      return new Buffer(stringContent).toString(encodingName2);
    }
    ZXingStringEncoding.customEncoder = (stringContent, encodingName) => {
      let encodingName2 = encodingName;
      if(encodingName.toLowerCase()=="iso-8859-1"){
        encodingName2="latin1";
      }
      return new Buffer(stringContent).toString(encodingName2);
    };
    let newData = DataMatrixDecodedBitStreamParser.decode(data);
    return bin2hex(newData.getText());
  }catch (e) {
    console.log(e);
  }
}
```

My function will return the original data as hex, so there is no problem with NUL, but you can also use hex2bin to get it as a Text if necessary.

I´m using the zxing polyfill for JS => https://github.com/zxing-js/library, cause JS does not Cut String like Objective C do.

I found out in Objective C NUL always will cut a string, so there is no solution yet.